# Filter ng-repeat table with multiple filter values for one column

Tags: angularjs

I've generated a dynamic table from array of objects and paginated the rows with angular-ui-bootstrap. I also need to implement row filter functionality in table based on user selections. For example, I would select one or more Cities from check-boxes and only the rows with matching Cities should be shown, or user will select certain names, or a combination of both. Below is sample data:

```
ctrl.data = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'Ram Kumar',
  city: 'Delhi',
  date: new Date("October 13, 2014 11:13:00")
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'Raman Kumar',
  city: 'Mumbai',
  date: new Date("November 13, 2014 11:13:00")
}, {
  id: 3,
  name: 'Raghav Kumar',
  city: 'Chennai',
  date: new Date("December 13, 2014 11:13:00")
}];
```

I've also created a metadata which will contain information about all properties of data such as property name, it's unique values, the kind of filter which this property would require i.e. check-box or a slider. Below is the metadata:

```
ctrl.metadata = [{
  name: "ID",
  values: [1, 2, 3],
  type: "checkbox",
  showFilter: false
}, {
  name: "Name",
  type: "checkbox",
  values: ["Ram Kumar", "Raman Kumar", "Raghav Kumar"],
  showFilter: false
}, {
  name: "City",
  type: "checkbox",
  values: ["Delhi", "Mumbai", "Chennai"],
  showFilter: true
}, {
  name: "Birth Date",
  type: "date",
  showFilter: false
}, {
  name: "Age",
  type: "slider",
  values: [18,26],
  showFilter: false
}];
```

I've currently made a one-value static filter query variable for some attributes such as ID, Name and City.

```
<div ng-repeat="attr in metadata">
    <div ng-if="attr.name === 'ID'">
      Enter Filter:
      <input type="textbox" ng-model="search.id" />
    </div>

    <div ng-if="attr.name === 'City'">
      Enter Filter:
      <input type="textbox" ng-model="search.city" />
    </div>
<div>
```

And I am applying this filter to table rows in this way:

```
  <tr ng-repeat="row in data | filter: search | pages: currentPage : itemsPerPage">
    <td ng-repeat="item in row">{{ item }}</td>
  </tr>
```

But firstly, I want the filter query variable (search) to be dynamically generated, as the data and metadata might change. Something like below if possible:

```
<div ng-repeat="attr in metadata">
    <div ng-if="attr.name === 'ID'">
      Enter Filter:
      <input type="textbox" ng-model="attr.searchQuery" />
    </div>
</div>
```

I attached the search query to metadata object property called searchQuery. But when I am trying to use it in filter, I see no result:

```
  <tr ng-repeat="row in data | filter: metadata[$index].searchQuery | pages: vm.currentPage : vm.itemsPerPage">
    <td ng-repeat="item in row">{{ item }}</td>
  </tr>
```

Secondly, the search query can take only one string, but as I want the filter to be based on more than one value, how can I achieve it? I've researched about custom filter but the problem is, how do I 'record' the selected values, and then send it to the filter (for example, get all the selected cities from check-boxes) ? I have to make every variable dynamic or part of metadata so that it does not break when either number of properties, or name of properties or values are changed. There might be no Cities but States when data is changed, so can't make anything static.

Please suggest some ideas for implementation.
[Here is a working plunker.](http://plnkr.co/edit/wukEuyLIqMpIyE7lp9Ce?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

First you should change your `<input>` to:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.selected[$index]" ng-true-value="'{{value}}'" ng-false-value="" /> {{value}}
```

Then your `ng-repeat`:

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in vm.data | filter: vm.search | customFilter: vm.selected | pages: vm.currentPage : vm.itemsPerPage">
```

And finally you can implement a `custom filter` to achieve what you want, like this:

```
.filter('customFilter', function() {
  return function(items, search) {
    if (!search || (Object.keys(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(search))).length === 0 && search.constructor === Object)) {
      return items;
    }
    var selected = Object.keys(search).map(function(key) {
      return search[key]
    });
    items = items.filter(function(value) {
      return selected.indexOf(value.city) != -1;
    });
    return items;
  }
});
```

Check the complete [**`code`**](http://plnkr.co/edit/WYcBQqkYuXKGSl1vIy2I?p=preview)

I hope it helps.

**Tip:** I don't know if you're using these things of `ui-bootstrap` in your real project, but they're deprecated, as you can see in console:

> PaginationController is now deprecated. Use UibPaginationController
>   instead. pagination is now deprecated. Use uib-pagination instead.

Comment: Great work, but the filter is working only on City. I can't filter based on ID or Name (trying to figure out but no solution yet). Also, when I try to check the ID or Name check-boxes, the City checkbox selections disappear (check-boxes of only one filter section can be selected at once). For example, if I select all the check-boxes of City and then select the first check-box of ID, then the first check-box of City disappears (because of the same filter model). Can't I attach the "selected[$index]" filter variable to my metadata? I want all the filters to persist simultaneously.

Comment: I tried to attach "selected[$index]" to attr instead of controller (vm), but even if I can see the selections being saved, I am not able to apply the filter to table using "customFilter: attr.selected"

Comment: Hmm.. you just speak about cities.. Do you want all filters working **simultanesoly**? How if you can only have a tab open (id **or** name for example)?

Comment: I mean, you can select a city (ex: Delhi), then suppose 5 records are obtained. Then, you close the city tab, and open ID tab to filter those 5 already-filtered records with ID (so there might remain 2-3 rows after City and ID simultaneous filter).

Comment: It will give you a lot of work.. consider use something done for it.. as SmartTable.

Comment: Sure, but I was wondering whether I can attach the selected[$index] to metadata property instead of a controller property (as you did). This way I would have the selection array available for each metadata object, and I can pass the array to custom filer like : "customFilter: metadataObject.selected" instead of "customFilter: vm.selected".

Comment: Well, you can pass the `attr` (the current element selected), however how can you get the current selected in `accordion-group`?

Comment: I am creating accordion group through metadata with ng-repeat="attr in vm.metadata". So I have each metadata object in every iteration. Can't I specify the ng-model of filter check-boxes as metadata object property like "ng-model="attr.selected[$index]"? So I can "save" the selections of every kind of filter (City, Name) in metadata, and retrieve and pass this selection to filter when creating table: <tr ng-repeat="row in vm.data | customFilter: attr.selected>. Please see this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/JQHL99xSXv8sGvIOrvAz?p=preview

Comment: Unfortunately you can't because your attr ends here: `<th ng-repeat="attr in vm.metadata">{{ attr.name }} </th>` Also, `attr.selected` don't give to you what you're expecting.. as I said what you're trying to do by hand is really hard to achieve..